# SBT - Failed to precise Play 2 app's project dependency

Tags: scala, jersey, playframework-2.0, sbt

I'm creating a play 2 project using Scala as main language and so need a rest client implemented in Scala.

Unfortunately, I can't easily use the known Java Jersey-Client.

I found on github this probably great api: [sjersey-client](https://github.com/FaKod/sjersey-client)

Using SBT as dependency management tool, I try to indicate to play app its dependency to sjersey:

```
object ApplicationBuild extends Build {

  val appName = "myWebapp"
  val appVersion = "1.0-SNAPSHOT"

  val appDependencies = Seq(
    jdbc,
    anorm
  )

  lazy val sjersey = RootProject(uri("git://github.com/FaKod/sjersey-client.git"))

  val main = play.Project(appName, appVersion, appDependencies).dependsOn(sjersey).settings(
    scalaVersion := "2.10.0"
  )

}
```

Then I run the command: `play reload update` but update failed:

```
[warn] Binary version (2.10) for dependency org.scala-lang#scala-library;2.10.0
[warn] in myWebapp#myWebapp_2.9.2;1.0-SNAPSHOT differs from Scala binary version in project (2.9.2).
[warn]  module not found: play#play_2.9.2;2.1-RC1              


[warn]  ::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::
[warn]  ::          UNRESOLVED DEPENDENCIES         ::
[warn]  ::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::
[warn]  :: play#play_2.9.2;2.1-RC1: not found
[warn]  :: play#play-jdbc_2.9.2;2.1-RC1: not found
[warn]  :: play#anorm_2.9.2;2.1-RC1: not found
[warn]  :: play#play-test_2.9.2;2.1-RC1: not found
[warn]  ::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::
[error] (mywebapp/*:update) sbt.ResolveException: unresolved dependency: play#play_2.9.2;2.1-RC1: not found
[error] unresolved dependency: play#play-jdbc_2.9.2;2.1-RC1: not found
[error] unresolved dependency: play#anorm_2.9.2;2.1-RC1: not found
[error] unresolved dependency: play#play-test_2.9.2;2.1-RC1: not found
[error] Total time: 4 s, completed 16 janv. 2013 19:36:37
```

But when I remove the `dependsOn` precision to Play! project, update and compilation are fine.

I'm blocked, what could be the issue?

Comment: What happens if you change the Scala version from 2.10.0 to 2.9.2? Also, what's the SBT version?

Comment: @Daniel C. Sobral I've just try with 2.9.2 => same error.   SBT version I use is: 0.12.1.   Very fuzzy ..

Comment: @Daniel C. Sobral I've updated the stacktrace, including its top

Comment: Does it have a link with the file: sbt.boot.properties.  Indeed, sbt uses 2.9.2 at origin.

Comment: Fork the sjersey-client.git and update the scala version to 2.10 in it. There is no play 2.1 compiled to scala 2.9.x in the repos.

Comment: @pedrofurla Indeed, sjersey is a maven project with scala 2.9.2 precised in the pom.xml. I changed this and that works, thanks ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can also try this if you don't want update sjersey scala version :

```
object ApplicationBuild extends Build {

  val appName = "myWebapp"
  val appVersion = "1.0-SNAPSHOT"

  val appDependencies = Seq(
    jdbc,
    anorm
  )

  val moreResolvers = resolvers ++= Seq(
    "fakod-releases"   at   "https://raw.github.com/FaKod/fakod-mvn-repo/master/releases",
    "fakod-snapshots"  at   "https://raw.github.com/FaKod/fakod-mvn-repo/master/snapshots")

  val main = play.Project(appName, appVersion, appDependencies).settings(
    moreResolvers,
    libraryDependencies ++= Seq(
      "org.scala-libs" % "sjersey-client" %  "0.2.0" intransitive)

  )

}
```